# Huawei Site Kit can't be access during app review testing

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

My application written in Flutter was submitted for review to release in Huawei App Gallery. However, my app got rejected because they cannot use a function in my app (Huawei site Kit search activity).

I have tested my app in my own device and also all the Huawei Devices in Cloud Debugging before submitting for review. My app can be run and work as expected.

I am not sure why the person who test my app cannot use the function in my app?  Any advice?

Comment: hi@Foody, Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: My App ID is 104789433 @shirley

Comment: hi@Foody, Could you mind provide your test apk for us to test? You can send it to hmscore@huawei.com.

Comment: Also, may i ask which API in the Site kit are you using?

Comment: If no result is found or the result is empty, you are advised to add an exception or prompt. By the way, do you need to locate before using the Site Kit function to search?

Comment: Hi, I have sent an email under the subject (APK Test_104789433). I am using Site Search Activity in Huawei Site Kit. I do not locate user before using the Site Search Activity. Based on the user selection from the result returned, I will get the longitude and latitude to be used for nearby place search later. @shirley

Answer (score 0):

According to the APK provided by you, we contacted the reviewer in Ireland. The reviewer reported that your application was rejected because the reviewer failed to obtain data during the local test.

Then we tested your apk and found:

- When the simulation locates to a European country such as France (48.74, 2.48), most options have results.
- But when the simulation locates to malaysia (5.23, 102.00), only click the **view all** option in the app, and all the nearby search result is displayed. Other options do not obtain data.

  [image]

Therefore, you can try to change the application release region, for example, to Europe, or change the parameters in your application and submit the application again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wish to release my application to Malaysia also but what do you mean by changing the parameters in my application? Is it for the nearby place search? @shirley

Comment: I have a question. I am able to obtain results even the location is in Malaysia using the cloud debugging devices. But why it doesn't work from the reviewer side?